# Divs in the same column won't align vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a "team" section for my website, where the `member_body` divs contained by the same column as the member `img` and member header above slip aside if I want to define their width. What can be the problem in this cases? I want them to vertically align and have the same width.

```css
.member {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.member img {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}
.member h3 {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}
.member_body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
.member_body span {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="team">
  <h1>Our Team</h1>
  <div class="separator2"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-md-6">
        <div class="member">
          <h3>Member One</h3>
          <img src="photos/team-member-1.jpg" alt="Team Member 1">
          <div class="member_body">
            <h5>Position</h5>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</br>Voluptates praesentium nulla cupiditate!</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-md-5">
        <div class="member">
          <h3>Member 2</h3>
          <img src="photos/team-member-2.jpg" alt="Team Member 2">
          <div class="member_body">
            <h5>Position</h5>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</br>Voluptates praesentium nulla cupiditate!</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: margin: 20px auto? in  member_body class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using 3 columns ( `col-md-6`+ `col-md-5` + `col-md-1`), just use 2 (`col-md-6` + `col-md-6`)

**UPDATE**

- add `margin:auto` to `member_body` if you want it to have the same `width` as the image and keep it centered as the image.
- remove `max-width:250px` from `img` in CSS and add `class="img-responsive"` to tag `img`

**Notes**

- added `col-xs-*` for demo
- your **`</br>`** is invalid, should be `<br>` or `<br />`

```css
.member {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.member img {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}
.member h3 {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}
.member_body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto
}
.member_body span {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="team">
  <h1>Our Team</h1>
  <div class="separator2"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="member">
          <h3>Member One</h3>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/250/200" alt="Team Member 1">
          <div class="member_body">
            <h5>Position</h5>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
              <br />Voluptates praesentium nulla cupiditate!</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="member">
          <h3>Member 2</h3>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/250/200" alt="Team Member 2">
          <div class="member_body">
            <h5>Position</h5>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates
              <br />praesentium nulla cupiditate!</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still, the last column is just for aesthetics and it's (supposed to be) totally separate, it's the same column as the col-md-5 above. I've tried it in my code, but it's still slipped apart :-/

Comment: Care to give a link for your site ? I'm not at the computer now but I'll take a look ASAP. I don't quiet understand whats the problem now.

Comment: In the meantime I've checked the margin: 0px auto; and it solved my problem! Maybe the issue was that the body's attributes didn't follow the img's attributes.

Comment: Look at my update.. I updated a few minutes ago but forgot to comment here

Comment: Now it definitely works, thank you! But I have one last question if you don't mind: where does the "img responsive" class inherit the desired size from, if no parent element is set precisely to that size? Just so I know in the future the way how to use it smartly. Thanks again! :)

Comment: In this case it doesn't inherit. But it won't just pass the parent col width. Because that class set max-width:100% to img. If this fixed your issue make sure you mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align them vertically use multiple `<div class="row">`

So, 1 team per `<div class="row">`

Comment: Not the team member I'd like to align, but the 2 member photos with the 2 member bodies :) Do you mean this way?

Comment: That's not what OP is looking for